# JQuery not working when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote some code in jquery: after clicking a box, I get some animation. I ran the code in code-pen and I don't have any problem. But when I tried the same code in my local server I saw that my jquery is not working. Here are the files.

```js
/* JSTransition.js */
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.trigger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid #999;
  background: #ddd;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.47, 0.32, 1.97);
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.47, 0.32, 1.97);
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.47, 0.32, 1.97);
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.47, 0.32, 1.97), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.47, 0.32, 1.97);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.trigger.clicked .box {
  -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
          transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSTransition.js"></script>
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

My css works fine. I also tested the animation (without clicks, just by refreshing the page) and it works fine too. When I click the box nothing happens.

Comment: try putting the js code in a document ready function

Comment: @aleskv you are right! Problem solved! But why can I run it normaly in codepen whithout document ready?

Comment: Probably because codepen executes the js code later

Comment: because in code pen scripts are included after your html is prepared and selector $('.trigger') gets DOM-elements

Comment: @aleskv Thank you for your time and for the answer :) . I have stuck for hours...

Comment: consider accepting the answer below so others will know the solution is correct

Answer (score 6):

You should wrap your event handler with `ready` function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

Or try to replace your script tag to closing body tag.

Comment: Thank you! That was missing.